# Can same function behave differently in mobile and desktop

Tags: mobile, responsive

I was seeing a website i.e. [website](http://www.kia.com/us/en/dealers/locator) if you give pincode and search, you will be provided with a listing. When i click on any listing the section shows up on map. But when i go on a mobile, i see that click works differently i.e. a section slides in. How is this done? does the same function work different in mobile and desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Cool effect, no?  So open up the site on your desktop.  Open it in Chrome.  Then open the Chrome Developer tools. I use right click --> Inspect.  Then on the top bar of the dev tools on the left hand side choose the icon "Device Mode" Select a device like an iphone or something.  Now you can simulate this (or any site) on a mobile device.  Its not a prefect simulation, just size and shape and general touch screen events like swipe and touch.

The design of this site uses some sort of javascript library to manage the transition. I've used jQuery Mobile in the past and this is exactly what it does.  I'm guessing Controls.js is the tool that's doing this here, but I'm not positive all the nuances of this site.  There are quite a few JS tools loaded here.

What ever happened to less is more, sigh?